# Multiple Tables or Multiple Schema

Tags: database-design, postgresql

[Postgresql: is it better using multiple databases with 1 schema each, or 1 database with multiple schemas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152405/postgresql-is-better-using-multiple-databases-with-1-schema-each-or-1-database)

I am new in schema concept for PostgreSQL.

For the above mentioned scenario, I was wondering

1. Why don't we use a single database (with default schema named public)
2. Why don't we have a single table, to store multiple users row?
3. Other tables which hold users related information, with foreign key point to the user table.

Can anyone provide me a real case scenario, which single database, multiple schema will be extremely useful, and can't solve by conventional single database, single schema.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/ddl-schemas.html

There are several reasons why one might want to use schemas:

```
*To allow many users to use one database without interfering with each other.
*To organize database objects into logical groups to make them more manageable.
*Third-party applications can be put into separate schemas so they do not collide with the names of other objects.
```

Schemas are analogous to directories at the operating system level, except that schemas cannot be nested.